# Parsing a String to an Integer

Tags: java, jgrasp

So my biggest problem is that I cannot seem to remember how to parse a string into an int so that I can idiot proof my code. My goal here is to find out if the user enters in a word instead of an int and then I can explain to them what an integer is. Can someone please help? I just need a simple list of parsing commands so that I can study them for use in the future, once there is a simple list I think I'll be able to figure all the others out from there.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
public class SelfTestNumberNine
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
   boolean test = false;
   int num = 0;
   int sum = 0;
   int count = 0;
   int pos = 0;
   int neg = 0;
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   while(!test)
   {
      num = 0;
      System.out.print("Enter in an Integer Value: ");
      String letta = in.next();
      if(??parsing stuff goes here!!)
      {
         num = in.nextInt();
         count++;
         if(num > 0)
         {
            pos++;
            sum = sum + num;
         }
         else if(num < 0)
         {
            neg++;
            sum = num + sum;
         }
         else
         {
             test = true;
         }
      }
      else
      {
         System.out.println("An Integer is a number that is positive or 
         negative,\nand does not include a decimal point.");
      }
   }//end while

   System.out.println("Total:   " + sum);
   double avg = sum / count;
   System.out.println("Average: " + avg);
  }//end main
}//end class
```

Basically, the program asks the user to input integers, counts the number of positive and negatives, and prints out the total and average (Ignoring 0). The program ends when the user inputs a 0.

P.S. Thanks for your time!! ]:-)

Comment: `Integer.parseInt()`? However this doesn't help if the user does not enter a number

Comment: And yes I have looked all over for something like this question, and all the answers are way too complicated for me to even start to comprehend...

Comment: I think you would be better to use the `hasNextInt()` method and loop while the user does not input a valid int

Comment: Integer.valueOf(), check here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html

Comment: will that return false if the user inputs a string?

Comment: @S.Nary No it would throw a `NumberFormatException`. `hasNextInt()` will return false if the user inputs a non int.

Comment: @Snare_Dragon if hasNextInt() is false, call nextLine() to throw away the line of input.

Comment: @GBlodgett   gotcha!!

Comment: @Snare_Dragon I posted an answer to try to clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to ensure that the user has entered an `int` without throwing an exception if they don't you can use the `hasNextInt()` method:

```
System.out.println("Enter an int (0) to quit");
//While the user has not entered a valid int
while (!input.hasNextInt()) {
    System.out.println("Please enter an integer: ");
    //Consume the bad input
    input.nextLine();
}
```

Which will loop until they enter a valid int. A sample run (`-` denotes user input):

```
Enter an int (0 to quit)
-No
Please enter an integer: 
-Never!!
Please enter an integer: 
-Ok ok fine
Please enter an integer: 
-3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two ways.

```
- Integer.parseInt()
- Integer.valueOf()

String myStr = "1";

int parsedInt = Integer.parseInt(myStr);
int valueOf = Integer.valueOf(myStr);

System.out.println("Parse Int: " + parsedInt);
System.out.println("Value Of: " + valueOf);
```

Note: You might get exception if the input is not parseable. `NumberFormatException`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a Boolean method and a try-catch to check if you can parse the string to an Integer.

```
public static boolean isInteger(String s) {
    try { 
        Integer.parseInt(s); 
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) { 
        return false; 
    } catch(NullPointerException e) {
        return false;
    }
    // only got here if we didn't return false
    return true;
}
```